# MySQL not starting and preventing os from booting to gui

Tags: boot, mysql, apparmor

Am using Ubuntu 18.10 which is running MySQL community latest, after os update and restart, it refuses to boot to gui. 
I can access the root account via recovery and I have tried a lot of solutions also from similar questions where I have thus far change folder and files ownership to mysql and given user and group read+write permission. Also added a local apparmor rule for mysqld this is now the current state in the photo couse can't copy the error log:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2GpL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue boils down to an out of storage, a natural fix will be to clear `log files`, `temporary files` and `trash files` this can however trigger more issues as the folders for `mysql` and `apache2` under the `/var/log` folder will not be there. after clearing, you will need to create those folders and give them the appropriate ownership and file permissions.

Other issues while running in recovery mode were:

1. checking disk information using both `df -Th` or `du` will show disparity between total, used and available space i.e. `total_disk_space - used_space > available_space` for me by 7Gb. for now my best guess is that it is the space reserved for recovery as i could create and save files in recovery.
2. The state of the disk seemed sketchy as regards read/write you might delete some files to free up space and they wont be deleted if such arise, well you wont see it until you restart and check again. so after deleting if it still refuses to boot go and check the deleted files again
3. File system check will not run before i freed up some space but forcing it worked by creating a file like so: `touch /forcefsck`